# Hide all tr whose id is not the value selected

Tags: javascript, c#, razor-pages

I have a razor pages project where i need the user to select between filtering between some ports and the names of variables, i kinda got the search bar working, but I can't make the other one work.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
<div class="col-12 border text-left p-3 mt-3" id="filterdiv">
    <div id="dropdown">
        @Html.DropDownList("ports", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["ports"], new { @id = "portdd" })
    </div>
    <div id="searchbar">
        <p>
            Name: <input type="text" name="SearchString" id="searchb"/>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>

@* FILTER BY PORTS *@
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#portdd').change(function () {
            var value = this.value;
            $('tr:gt(0):not($(#' + value + '):attr(id))').hide();
        });
    });
</script>

@* FILTER BY NAME *@
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#searchb').change(function () {
            var value = this.value;
            $('tr:gt(0):not(:contains(' + value + '))').hide();
        });
    });
</script>
```

But it's not working as intended. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please define "*not working as intended*". Also, I suspect you need to `show` something at some point (if you only `hide` things everytime your filter changes, you will end up with nothing shown)

Comment: Please create a [mre] using the final HTML and a suitable demo table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('tr:gt(0)[id !=' + value + ']').hide();`

if I understand correctly

Comment: thank you! yes this is what I needed, I'm not very handy with javascript. thank you again!